Highlight overlapping time in Google sheet for a range of data with Start and End Time in Columns
PART A
There are multiple rows of data in a Google Sheet with start and end times in the format as shown in the picture. This data is already processed and filtered out from a larger data set to display only today's date. How can I highlight entire row with overlapping times in those fixed rows of data(could be maximum 30-35 rows of filtered data for any given day?
Sample Data-Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rgLpTlQfhWRQgPLlX4OLPzdMfinCMeftvUTcd6GJOMw/edit?usp=sharing
Desired Output:

PART B
It may also be helpful if the time which are logged-in in the above table of start and end time, can show up as grey-highlight in the below time-table(this will indicate that the time is not available OR green-highlight the time which are not yet punched to show their availability).
Time Blocks:

Thought to use vlookup formula, but that will highlight only the first encounter and any subsequent overlap may not be captured.
Then tried to use match function: =ISNUMBER(MATCH(R2,N:N,0)). But that is not taking effect in the conditional format custom formula space.
I am open to solutions involving App Script OR in-cell conditional formatting with custom formulas.

Welcome to SO! Please avoid sharing images as your data, and share it rather as a text table and, if necessary, as a sample sheet.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! I noticed that this post has 2 parts. Please edit your post and only ask one question per post.

As the above comment states, if you want an answer to your "part B", ask a new question with that section.


highlight entire row with overlapping times

Condense the various "start" columns into one column like this:
=byrow(D2:G, lambda(row, if(len(join("", row)), max(row), iferror(ø))))

Then collect workers whose bookings overlap like this:
=let( 
  workers, arrayformula(B2:B & " (row " & row(B2:B) & ")"), 
  starts, K2:K, 
  ends, J2:J, 
  map(starts, ends, lambda(s, e, 
    iferror(join(", ", 
      filter(workers, row(s) <> row(starts), s < ends, e > starts) 
    )) 
  )) 
)

Finally, use a conditional formatting custom formula rule to paint rows where an overlapping booking was found:
=len($L2)


See Solution.

Thank you @doubleunary! Seems like exactly what I was looking for.
Just to be sure, the column L has nothing to do with the solution and I believe it can be safely deleted?
Let me implement this solution in my main sheet and run few tests. I may comeback, If I face any issues.

Column L does all the heavy lifting. You can hide it if it gets in the way.

Here is an alternative solution for which you don't need to add any auxiliary columns. Simply select the whole range A2:J, apply conditional formatting, and in the custom function input, like so:

; enter the following formula:
=LET(start, TOCOL($D$2:$G, 1, TRUE), ROWS(QUERY({start, FILTER($J$2:$J, $J$2:$J<>"")}, "where (Col1 < datetime '" & TEXT($J2, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") &"' and Col2 > datetime '" & TEXT(INDEX(start, ROW($A2)-1), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & "')", 0)) > 1)

Output:

References

TEXT
QUERY
ROWS
TOCOL
LET
INDEX
FILTER

